# How to prevent race conditions in Mongodb / NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm not even sure if this has a specific name , but here is the scenario:

- User 1 and user 2 both access a record in the database ( so they effectively have the same record )
- User 1 updates the record
- User 2 trys to update the record , but because the data has changed , it should fail.

When I was programming with C# and SQL server , If a table had a timestamp in it the Entity Framework ( database framework for .Net ) would automatically handle this and fail the updates for modified data.

Is there anything like this in MongoDB / NodeJS?

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in timestamp functionality in mongodb but mongoose could be of help in that case:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB concurrency transaction model is not evident but available visit -
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/

Answer (score 0):

I personally would suggest staying away from mongoose.

What you could do is create a `locked` property:

1. User 1 tries to update a record, it starts with `findOneAndUpdate({locked: null, ...restOfConditions})` and sets `locked` to true.
2. User 2 tries to update a record, it fails to `findOne` because part of condition is to always query for `{locked: null}`.
3. User 1 finishes updating a record, it as part of last update, it unsets `locked`.

This obviously needs to be implemented by you but I hope it gives you the idea of approach I would pick.